# Score aggregation results in ElasticSearch

Tags: function, elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation

I created a type named `test` that consists of a `prices` nested field.

Each document can consist of several prices and each price consists of `price` and `date`:

```
...
"prices":[{  
      "date" : "2017-02-08T16:04:20.424Z",
      "price" : 120
   },
   {  
      "date" : "2017-02-08T17:35:01.424Z",
      "price" : 70
   }]
...
```

I'm trying to create a search query that will first aggregate the prices of each document to the minimum `price` and then score all the minimum values returned from the aggregation using a linear decay function

I currently have an aggregation query on all documents:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "prices" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "prices"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "min_price" : { "min" : { "field" : "prices.price" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That returns the minimum price in `test`.

And a linear decay function that scores the nested `prices` of all the documents un-aggregated:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "prices",
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "linear": {
                    "prices.price": { 
                      "origin": "50", 
                      "offset": "50",
                      "scale":  "20"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

That returns a score for each document.
Problem is, I don't know based on what `price` in the nested `prices` field it calculates the score.

Any ideas?